# Starting JBPM demo

Tags: wildfly, jbpm

I am trying to start the demo version of JBPM  7.26.0 (windows).

After a successful "ant start.demo", the wildfly server log fills up with

> WARN  [org.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil] (Thread-149) Unable
> to load key store. Using password from configuration

http://localhost:8080/jbpm-casemgmt/jbpm-cm.html never loads after logging in (spins indefinitely).

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beside the Single Zip Distribution you can also try the [provided Docker builds](https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html).

Just [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) and run `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name jbpm-server-full jboss/jbpm-server-full:7.26.0.Final` and browse to http://localhost:8080/business-central

This works fine for me.